# IntelliJ Tomcat Console Color Output

Tags: tomcat, colors, intellij-idea, console

I run Tomcat 7.x under IntelliJ 12.x.  When I deploy a Tomcat webapp, there is a pane in IntelliJ dedicated to Tomcat console output and certain logs.

Is there a way to get IntelliJ to apply colors to the text in the console output?  I'm flexible about how this could be accomplished, although simpler and more elegant answers are preferable of course.

I will be glad to clarify this question as needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered the plugin 'Grep Console' which allows me to colorize things, even parts of lines. Pretty cool.